# Hash change when on click

Tags: jquery

I'm doing for the scrolling function for a project, but how can I make the hash show out in the URL too when we on click each of the different a[href=#] ?
example when click for button home, it scroll to page content id which is #home, but the URL also got the hash URL .../#home.

```
   $(".scrollable").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this.hash).offset() ? $(this.hash).offset().top : 0;
    var customoffset = 170;
    $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop:target - customoffset
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

you dont need to use jquery to do this, you can just use html:

on the tag `a` use `# +the name of the tag` you what to jump

```
<a href="#heading">Click here to jump</a>
<a href="#another-heading">Click here to jump</a>

<h2 id="heading">Some Heading</h2>
<h2 id="another-heading">Another Heading</h2>
```

example with the effect, need to be tested on local to see the #hash:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<style>
body { 
  font: 14px/2 Georgia, serif; 
}

    #page-wrap { 
      max-width: 500px; 
      margin: 1rem auto;
      padding: 1rem;
    }

    h1, h2 {
      line-height: 1.2;
    }

    p, ul, h1 { 
      margin: 0 0 1rem 0; 
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    // Select all links with hashes
    $('a[href*="#"]')
      // Remove links that don't actually link to anything
      .not('[href="#"]')
      .not('[href="#0"]')
      .click(function(event) {
        // On-page links
        if (
          location.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//, '') 
          && 
          location.hostname == this.hostname
        ) {
          // Figure out element to scroll to
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) + ']');
          // Does a scroll target exist?
          if (target.length) {
            // Only prevent default if animation is actually gonna happen
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000, function() {
              // Callback after animation
              // Must change focus!
              var $target = $(target);
              $target.focus();
              if ($target.is(":focus")) { // Checking if the target was focused
                return false;
              } else {
                $target.attr('tabindex','-1'); // Adding tabindex for elements not focusable
                $target.focus(); // Set focus again
              };
            });


     }
    }
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="page-wrap">

  <h1 id="top">Smooth Page Scrolling</h1>

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#two">Scroll to Section Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">Scroll to Section Three</a></li>
  </ul>

  <h2 id="one">Section One</h2>

  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>

  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>

  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>

  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>

  <h2 id="two">Section Two</h2>

  <p><a href="#top">Top</a></p>

  <p>quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum
    sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus,
    tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>

  <h2 id="three">Section Three</h2>

  <p><a href="#top">Top</a></p>

  <p>quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum
    sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus,
    tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>

  <p>quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est. Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum
    sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus,
    tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor, facilisis luctus, metus</p>

  <p>Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Vestibulum tortor quam, feugiat vitae, ultricies eget, tempor sit amet, ante. Donec eu libero sit amet quam egestas semper. Aenean ultricies mi vitae est.
    Mauris placerat eleifend leo. Quisque sit amet est et sapien ullamcorper pharetra. Vestibulum erat wisi, condimentum sed, commodo vitae, ornare sit amet, wisi. Aenean fermentum, elit eget tincidunt condimentum, eros ipsum rutrum orci, sagittis tempus
    lacus enim ac dui. Donec non enim in turpis pulvinar facilisis. Ut felis. Praesent dapibus, neque id cursus faucibus, tortor neque egestas augue, eu vulputate magna eros eu erat. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nam dui mi, tincidunt quis, accumsan porttitor,
    facilisis luctus, metus</p>

</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: yaya actually i already tried,but it don't have the animate scroll effect uhm

Comment: @xx_secretpooh something like this https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/smooth-scrolling/#article-header-id-1 ?

Comment: yaya :) if do this way, it cant show out the #hash , cuz problem now i want to show the hash in the url too when on click :(

Comment: @xx_secretpooh the #hash will work but in the example cannot work because it is like an iframe, just try ;) i put full example just create a .html to test on local

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want hashtag in URL then you can use history API to do that.

`history.replaceState({}, document.title, ".");`

Answer (score 0):

Scroll with animated

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
 
 $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
        var target = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
        if (target.length) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
    });
```

```css
.testbox .nav{position:fixed; width:100%; top:0; left:0; background:#fff;}
.testbox .nav a{border:1px solid #ccc; margin:5px 10px; display:inline-block; padding:5px}
.testfld div{width:100%; background:#063; padding:300px 0; color:#fff; text-align:center; border:2px solid #fff;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testbox">
<div class="nav">
<a class="scrollable" href="#a1" >A1 Box</a>
<a class="scrollable" href="#a2" >A2 Box</a>
<a class="scrollable" href="#a3" >A3 Box</a>
<a class="scrollable" href="#a4" >A4 Box</a>
</div>
<div class="testfld">
<div id="a1">A1 Box</div>
<div id="a2">A2 Box</div>
<div id="a3">A3 Box</div>
<div id="a4">A4 Box</div>
</div>
</div>
```